# Is there a way to reuse a NHibernate SessionFactory for multiple databases?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sessionfactory, pooling

Like the title says, is there a way to "reuse" a `SessionFactory` for multiple databases? Since instantiating the `SessionFactory` takes time, I wonder if it would be possible to pool these instances and reuse them, changing only the connection/database name. Obviously, first level cache would be cleared, but I am trying to avoid the penalty involved in instantiating the factory itself.

The background is that I can have several small "pluggable" databases with exactly the same schema, so there is no need for NHibernate to rebuild all mappings every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically create `Session` instances from the same session factory for different databases by first opening a standard ADO.NET `Connection` object appropriate for the target database and passing it to the NH `SessionFactory` instance like this:

```
    var connection = new SqlConnection("target DB connection string");
    var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(connection);
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
```

I recommend you use a Dependency Injection container to control the lifetime and disposal of the ADO.NET connection instance instead of creating it directly as shown in the simplified code shown above.

Another gotcha is that NHibernate performs database access when the `SessionFactory` instance is spun up so you need to either provide a valid connection string in the hibernate.cfg.xml file or dynamically inject that into the session factory configuration logic.

## UPDATE:

Groo provided a [link to a great post](http://patrickhuber.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/change-connectionstring-nhibernate/) on dynamically switching databases in NHibernate. Follow the advice in that post rather than doing something like the sample code shown above.

Comment: +1 thanks, I realized this overload existed after I posted the question, however [this link here](http://patrickhuber.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/change-connectionstring-nhibernate/) mentions some problems with transactions: *[When this overload is used] second level cache will be disabled for tracking statements in the same transaction. What this means in reality is you get one of these nasty errors when trying to call ISession.Save(object obj) from within a transaction*. Did you have similar experiences?

Comment: We handle that through our unit of work implementation. It receives the connection, performs a BeginTransaction() on the `Session` instance, and populates a module level field to hold the NHibernate `ITransaction` instance that it returns. It explicitly calls `Commit()` or `Rollback()` depending on the state of the processing. We have had issues when the database takes a long time to process the NHibernate requests but rollback handles that cleanly.

Comment: Sorry, just saw the link, our processes are really write oriented so we haven't seen that kind of problem.

Comment: We did implement something very similar to the code in post for `CreateSessionFactory` which is what I was referring to in the answer about the session factory configuration. The code in that post looks pretty solid and I would have included that link if I've been aware of it. Thanks for sharing!!