# How to obtain an NHibernate session with a connection that has an active transaction

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

We are usin NHibernate as our DAL for the domain model.
At the end of a bulk process I want to do some actions using the NHibernate DAL

Something like:

```
public void BulkUpdate()
{
   var connection =  new sqlConnection(“connectonstring”);
   var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
   // Do Bulk Stuff
   var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession(connection);
   var result = session.Query<DomainClass>();
   // Do Stuff with Result
   transaction.Commit();
   connection.Close();     
}
```

The read attempt of NHibernate fails, because it tries to use a command object, that has no transaction set. But I do not know of a way to pass the transaction object to it.

Any Nhibernate guru's out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this approach might work but don't have time right now to verify it:

- *First*, create an NHibernate session from your connection string as shown [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745046/is-there-a-way-to-reuse-a-nhibernate-sessionfactory-for-multiple-databases?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- Open the transaction like this: `session.BeginTransaction()`
- Use the `session.Connection` property to perform the bulk stuff
- Complete the processing with the `session` and commit as appropriate

Comment: Your approach was right. I updated the answer with steps I needed to propagate the transaction to the SQL commands for the bulk stuff. Thanks again!