# NHibernate session factory count limit?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am creating multiple session factories through code (not config file)
The problem I'm having is that after the 20th session factory creation, I start getting an exception (MappingException), and I don't know why.

Regardless of the order, it goes bad after the 20th. Sessions are successfully created as long as they are in the first 20 of them.

MappingException message: Unique suffix 100_ length must be less than maximum 4 characters

any help is appreciated.

```
public static void AddPortfolioToConnectionstrings(string portfolio, string 
connectionString)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration()
            .Configure()
            .SessionFactoryName(portfolio)
            .SetProperty("connection.connection_string", connectionString);

        ...

        _portfolios.Add(portfolio, configuration.BuildSessionFactory());
    }
```

Comment: why would you need 20 session factories?  Are you connecting to 20 different databases?  also include your code.

Comment: yes, I'm connecting to over 20 different db's.

Comment: All of those session factories are going to eat up a lot of memory.  Have you thought about hiding these session factories behind a webapi layer so that each sessionfactory can live in it's own space?

Comment: thank you Fran. Can you please elaborate about the 'own space' idea, how do you see it achieved by using an api layer?

Comment: if you wrapped each one of those session factories in their own webapi projects and accessed the webapi project, you are isolating them, running them in their own address space.  but when I look at an app that is connecting to 20 different db's through nhibernate, you might be using the wrong tech.  Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745046/is-there-a-way-to-reuse-a-nhibernate-sessionfactory-for-multiple-databases) it discusses dynamically changing the connection of the SessionFactory as opposed to spinning up multiple ones.

Answer (score 3):

As usual the error messages of NHibernate aren't helping anyone.

In my case I had this error:

> MappingException message: Unique suffix 100_ length must be less than maximum 4 characters

After intensive research, the cause of this error was that the connection string had the wrong server address, and then wrong credentials supplied.

---

About your question: having 20 destination databases to connect to is unusual, but it can be done. With the implementation I show you below, I use 12 session factories, but make sure you run your code in a 64-bit process space, otherwise it will quickly eat up the memory available to a 32-bit process.

The only thing you need to look out for is that you need to have a custom Session factory builder that you bind as a singleton. A lightweight version of my implementation looks like this:

```
public interface ISessionFactoryBuilder
{
    IDictionary<string, ISessionFactory> SessionFactories { get; }
}

public IDictionary<string, ISessionFactory> SessionFactories { get; private set; }
    private readonly IConfigurationManager _configurationManager;

    public SessionFactoryBuilder(IConfigurationManager configurationManager)
    {
        this._configurationManager = configurationManager;

        this.SessionFactories = this.BuildSessionFactories();
    }

    private IDictionary<string, ISessionFactory> BuildSessionFactories()
    {
        var sessionFactories = new Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        var connectionStrings = this._configurationManager.GetConnectionStrings();

        if (connectionStrings.Count == 0)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("No connection descriptions can be found!");

        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings item in connectionStrings)
            if (item.Name != "LocalSqlServer" && item.Name != "OraAspNetConString")
                sessionFactories.Add(item.Name, this.InitializeSessionFactory(item.ConnectionString, item.ProviderName));

        return sessionFactories;
    }

    private class Connectiontypes
    {
        public string Db_type { get; set; }
        public FluentConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    }

    private ISessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory(string connectionString = "", string providerName = "")
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{connectionString}");

        List<SessionFactoryBuilder.Connectiontypes> conntypes = new List<SessionFactoryBuilder.Connectiontypes> {
            new SessionFactoryBuilder.Connectiontypes
            {
                Db_type = "System.Data.SqlClient",
                Configuration = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql() 
                    .Dialect<XMsSql2005Dialect>()) },
            new SessionFactoryBuilder.Connectiontypes
            {
                Db_type = "System.Data.OracleDataClient",
                Configuration = Fluently.Configure().Database(OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                    .ConnectionString(connectionString).Provider<NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider>()
                    .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleManagedDataClientDriver>()
                    .Dialect<XOracle10gDialect>().ShowSql())
            },
            new SessionFactoryBuilder.Connectiontypes
            {
                Db_type = "System.Data.MySQLDataClient", Configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql())
            }
        };

        FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = conntypes.Find(x => x.Db_type == providerName).Configuration;

        fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
        {
            x.SetProperty("command_timeout", "120");
        });

#if DEBUG
        fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
        {
            x.SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor());
        });
#endif

        var mappings = fluentConfiguration.Mappings(m =>
        {
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UsersMap>();
        });

        var config = mappings.BuildConfiguration();

        foreach (PersistentClass persistentClass in config.ClassMappings)
        {
            persistentClass.DynamicUpdate = true;
        }

        var sessionFactory = mappings
#if DEBUG
            .Diagnostics(d => d.Enable(true))
            .Diagnostics(d => d.OutputToConsole())
#endif
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.SessionFactories.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in this.SessionFactories)
            {

                item.Value.Close();
                item.Value.Dispose();
            }

            this.SessionFactories = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I bind this with NInject as:

```
Bind<ISessionFactoryBuilder>().To<SessionFactoryBuilder>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("configurationManager", context => context.Kernel.Get<IConfigurationManager>());
```

Of course you have to execute this anywhere near your program startup, or as we call it the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

The only thing missing here is the obvious implementation of the IConfigurationManager, which is just my custom wrapper around [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx), that gets passed in to the constructor of `SessionFactoryBuilder`.

This way you can have your Session factory builder built at application startup and never again (obviously until the appdomain gets restarted or so), therefore you won't have memory leaks or OutOfMemory exceptions for having that many SessionFactories hanging around and getting created.